# Receiving "Stream encountered HTTP error: 403" when using Twitter API. What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am very new to using the Twitter API and was testing some Python code (below)

```
from tweepy import OAuthHandler 
from tweepy import Stream

import twitter_credentials

class StdOutListener(Stream):
    def on_data(self, data):
        print(data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

twitter_stream = StdOutListener(
  twitter_credentials.CONSUMER_KEY, twitter_credentials.CONSUMER_KEY_SECERET,
  twitter_credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN, twitter_credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECERET
)
twitter_stream.filter(track=['#bitcoin'])
```

but whenever I try to run it, it would give this repeating error "Stream encountered HTTP error: 403". I checked the Twitter API response codes and error 403 was listed as the request is forbidden.

Here are some troubleshooting steps I already took:

1. tried new access keys/consumer keys
2. tried to create a new developer account
3. uninstall and reinstall tweepy

None of these worked for me. So what is causing this error and how can I fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Essential access, you won’t be able to access Twitter API v1.1.

See [the FAQ section about this in Tweepy's documentation](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-am-i-encountering-a-403-forbidden-error) for more information.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, is there a way to access Twitter API v1.1 or remove essential access?

Comment: Yes, `Apply for additional access within the developer portal` as it says in the Twitter documentation.

Comment: @AndyPiper, isn't "POST /2/tweets/search/stream/rules" supposed to come under v2 ? If yes, isn't there any equivalent in Tweepy for this ? Stream.filter() makes use of v1.1 but I can't find anything under Client in tweepy. Does this mean I'll have to directly make the API calls ? Starting out with REST APIs, apologies in advance for asking a noob question

Comment: Tweepy doesn't support streaming with API v2 yet. See https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1472.

Answer (score 0):

Use `StreamingClient` instead of `Streaming` from Tweepy if you only have Essential Access (Twitter API v2). The bearer token is enough for StreamingClient.

For more information about its use:
https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/streamingclient.html#tweepy.StreamingClient