# Python tweepy Unexpected parameter: track Stream encountered HTTP error: 400

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am using tweepy but there was an error encountered

"Unexpected parameter: track
Stream encountered HTTP error: 400"

Here is my code:

```
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import tweepy
import config

authenticate = tweepy.OAuthHandler(config.API_KEY, config.API_SECRET)

authenticate.set_access_token(config.ACCESS_TOKEN, config.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)


class StdOutListener(tweepy.StreamingClient):
    def on_data(self,data):
        print(data)
        return True

    def on_error(self,status):
        print(status)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    listener = StdOutListener(config.BEARER_TOKEN)

    listener.filter(track=['donald trump', 'hillary clinton', 'barack obama', 'twitter'])
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: similar problem - maybe solutions is also similar: [python - Receiving "Stream encountered HTTP error: 403" when using Twitter API. What is causing this error and how can I fix it? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70031766/receiving-stream-encountered-http-error-403-when-using-twitter-api-what-is-c)

Comment: Thank you, I've got access to Elevated.

Comment: Here is the full error @furas. Unexpected parameter: track
Stream encountered HTTP error: 400... hope you can help me thank you

Comment: read my previous comment - put **FULL error**, put **in question (not in comments)**

Answer (score 0):

[`StreamingClient.filter`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.10.0/streamingclient.html#tweepy.StreamingClient.filter) doesn't support a `track` parameter.
You'll want to use [`StreamingClient.add_rules`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.10.0/streamingclient.html#tweepy.StreamingClient.add_rules) beforehand instead.
See [Tweepy's documentation on using `StreamingClient`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.10.0/streaming.html#using-streamingclient) for more information.

Comment: how can you add multiple keywords in add_rule? when one keywords is search it will display it? thank you

Comment: You can refer to https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-query for information on how to build rules. For further questions, you should create new questions rather than commenting.